# How to detect a key-press with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a shooting game in pygame, but this code:

```
checkfocus = pygame.key.get_focused()
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
#THIS PART DOES NOT WORK
            if event.type == pygame.K_w:
                print(checkfocus)
                print("up")
                pygame.key.set_repeat(0, 1)
                yvalue -= 20
                if yvalue < 0:
                    yvalue = 0
                print(yvalue)
                pygame.time.wait(100)
                screen.fill((52, 61, 82))
                screen.blit(harryshoot, (20, yvalue))
                pygame.display.flip()
```

somehow doesn't work, despite other `if event.type` codes working just fine. Whats the problem here? Why is it only this code that does not get keyboard input? I have tried changing the keys, but that didn't help.(`print("up")` also does not show up so it's not the code itself which is not working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.K_w` is not an event type, but a key. You need to verify that the event type is `pygame.KEYDOWN` and the key is `pygame.K_w`:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key== pygame.K_w:
                # [...]
```

The keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) create a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object with additional attributes. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute (e.g. `K_RETURN` , `K_a`) and the `mod` attribute contains a bitset with additional modifiers (e.g. `KMOD_LSHIFT`). The `unicode` attribute provides the Unicode representation of the keyboard input.